# Java Convert Map<String,Set<String>> to Map<String, Set<Object1>>

Tags: java, dictionary, stream

i want to convert `Map<String,Set<String>>` to `Map<String, Set<Object1>>`

```
class Object1 {
    String name;
}
```

i tried this way but not working.

```
Map<String, Set<Object>> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey(), 
                        Collectors.mapping(x -> (Set<Object1>)Object1.builder().name(x.getValue()), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Show us some of these "various methods". Maybe one of them is almost correct and only needs a small change. Maybe your approach is totally wrong and by seeing your incorrect attempt we will be able to explain what's wrong with your thought process.

Comment: Map<String, Set<Object>> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey(), 
                        Collectors.mapping(x -> (Set<Object1>)Object1.builder().name(x.getValue()), Collectors.toSet())));    -- this is what i tried

Comment: Please edit your question to include the extra details. Comments are not able to format code in a readable way

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. But you can add name field constructor to your Object1 and try this code

```
map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                        entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                .map(Object1::new)
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done quite simply with the help of `toMap` collector:

```java
Map<String, Set<Object1>> newMap = map.entrySet()
    .stream() // or parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue()
              .stream()
              .map(s -> Object1.builder().name(s).build())
              .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    ));
```